# Sorting model with child_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have model Category

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :child, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'category_id'
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category'
  mount_uploader :photo, ImageUploader
end
```

And have some data in db. For example:

```
> ID Name category_id
> 1 Moto null
> 2 Breaks 1
> 3 Car null
> 4 Tires 3
> 5 Brembo 2
> 6 Komo 4
```

And I don`t know how sorting Model for first parent and after go child. For example:

```
ID Name category_id 
1 Moto null 
2 Breaks 1 
5 Brembo 2
4 Car null 
5 Tires 4 
6 Komo 5
```

And insert this data into

```
= f.collection_select(:category_id, @category, :id, :name, {:prompt=>false}, {class:'select', :multiple=>'multiple'})
```

Comment: So you want to sort by category_id ? Like the result should be `Breaks-1 Brembo-2 Somthing-3 Tires-4 Komo-5` ?

Comment: Yes, I need sorting by category_id

Comment: Have you tried something as basic as `@category.sort_by{|cat| [cat.id,cat.category_id]}`. `#sort_by` can accept and `Array` and it will sort them in order by each value. To sort by just `category_id` it would be `@category.sort_by(&:category_id)`. Also since this is a collection i would recommend changing the naming to `@categories` as this indicates clearly that there are or may be more than 1